# Custom CMake configuration type. Can I somehow "inherit" from Debug?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

I'm using CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES to target two architectures.  This seemed like the only way to do this in CLion.

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug_x86_64;Debug_aarch64")

My custom config types don't seem to include the Debug flags, not that I would expect them to.  How could I do that?  Inheriting, so to speak, from the default options such as "Debug" would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

CMake holds compiler flags in the CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CONFIGURATION} and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CONFIGURATION} for the C and C++ respectively

The easies way to "inherit" flags would be:

```
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_Debug_x86_64 ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG})
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_Debug_x86_64 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
```